# Filter Example for VSTSDK2.4 Source

Tags: audio, filter, signal-processing, vst

Is there anywhere an existing example how to implement a dsp filter for exactly the vstsdk2.4?
I mean something like the source examples included in vstsdk (.h and .cpp file) for easy understanding how this will work. 
Searched very long on web, found vrey much about filter design, but nothing of this is useful for me (at the moment and my knowledge). 
Every example would be very welcome...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not read it in depth, but here is a KVR-Audio thread that might contain the info you need.

http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=249926

The KVR Audio DSP forum is a very good place to ask these questions:
http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I found one Link. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but a real good beginning.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/teragonaudio

I have implemented a few open source filters  there which you can look at. Although they are built on Juce, it seems that you are looking for DSP algorithms, not so much the VST boilerplate stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. But what I am looking for: a simple commented Tutorial of a e.g. one pole Lowpass or Hipass Filter build with the Steinberg VST SDK 2.4. I have not found any tutorial on the web for this SDK, so slowly I think I'm the only man in the world learn programming VST pugins with Steinberg's SDK.